# How to stop inheritance of CSS applied to global scope inside Angular's Emulated Encapsulation?

Tags: css, angular, asp.net-mvc

We have an Angular Application inside an ASP.NET MVC View,
So inside `.cshtml` we have this:

```html
<app-root></app-root>
```

There are styles applied to the entire ASP.NET app which are colliding with the Angular components. Note that, Native `ShadowDom` encapsulation is not an option for me due to it's limited support of browsers.

I am limiting the scope by having the styles applied to each component (Emulated version),

Assume this is my ASP.NET view with it's own set of `styles/stylesheets` specified as below and there is `<app-root></app-root>` is where I am having my app which holds other components, I want to stop the styles in the style tag to bleed over my `app-root`. How can I achieve this?

```html
<body>
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: powderblue;
    }

    h1 {
        color: blue;
    }

    p {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either not timport the global stylesheet or you can overrwrite those global styles. Since these rules are written as global, they must be overwritten in some way. (They can’t be ignored).

Eg.

```
    body {
        background-color: white;
    }

    h1 {
        color: black;
    }

    p {
        color: black;
    }
```

Comment: I am not importing a global css into my app, they are on the head of the page where I have my angular template rendered, so they get inherited to the members within my application, overriding doesn't seem to be a great option, there just are way too many elements I would be looking at, also will not be considered as a best practice.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I don't see any other options beyond removing the rules or overriding them. Good luck.